# How to create a UI link in A-frame

Tags: aframe

I am looking to add a piece of text to the camera on an A-frame scene which will act as a link to transfer to a non-VR page.

```
<a-entity camera look-controls position="0 0 0">
<a-cursor visible="false">
  </a-cursor>
        <a-entity text="value: Galleries; color: black; width: 2;" position="-0.25 0.7 -1" onClickLink>
</a-entity>
</a-entity>
```

The onClickLink function is registered and uses `window.location.href = "https://www.google.com";` to change page as suggested in the docs.

I have created a gallery, and want to give users a simple UI link at the top to take them back to a list of other galleries - however - in the example above the onClickLink function just gets applied to the whole scene rather than only the piece of text. I guess it has maybe been applied to its parent - the camera - so any click counts as firing the event? Or do I need to add something to the event to determine what object was clicked? I'm not sure how raycasting would work on something in the top left corner of the camera?

I do not want to use a 3D object in the scene, and I similarly don't want to use the Link portal entity that will be placed in the scene (I did try going down this route similar to the above, and it again just applied the link to the entire scene rather than on clicking the link itself).

Is there a way to achieve what I'm after?

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard html elements and a-frame element to gather and use Css (position: fixed; z-index: 999) to bring it forward to the top but to create an external html link I share part of my code hope you find the idea, you can use jquery(or pure javascript) to add click event to your a-frame objest, but first add below code to **<a-camera** tag:

```
raycaster="far: 10000; objects: .clickable"
```

then add "clickable" class name to any A-frame object you want to be clicked by user

```
<a-image visible=true id="web" class="clickable external" src="#imgweb" alpha-test="0.5" position="-0.14 -0.9 0" height="0.18" width="0.18"></a-image>
```

and then like any html dom object you can access to aframe objects by javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {

    $(".external").each(function(index) {
        $(this).on("click", function() {

            console.log(this.id + ' Pushed');

            switch (this.id.toLowerCase()) {
                case 'web':
                    window.open("http://www.farsix.com/");
                    break;
                case 'instagram':
                    window.open("https://www.instagram.com/");
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log("Unknown Link!");
            };
        });
    });

};
```